# Unwanted top margin when using ViewPager2 with TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I have a TabLayout with a ViewPager2 attached.
I attach my fragments to it like normal but I have an odd behaviour.

[image: To much top margin]

Between the TabLayout and the TextView there is some kind of gap although my Textview **should be** in the very top left corner. I cannot figure out where this extra margin is coming from (It does not matter what kind of view I place into the fragment it seems the whole fragment is shifted down (But the actual background of my fragment covers the entire ViewPager area)

This is the code for the viewPager und TabLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorSecondary"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMinWidth="48dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/App.Tab.Text"
    app:tabTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryLight"/>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightRed"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I only added the background color to see which view is "below" the margin

This is the code for the fragment.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightOrange"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NO MARGIN TOP LEFT"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Where does my margin come from? It drives me nuts. I do not change margins inside the code whatsoever.

I use a custom FragmentStateAdapter which might be the culprit? On a sidenot the first click on a tab after the app opens will not switch the page, I could not make this work yet any idea why?

Here is the Adapter I use:

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
private static final String TAG = "TabAdapter";
private final List<TabFragment> mFragments;
private final String prefix;
private final ViewPager2 mViewPager;
private final TabLayout mTabLayout;
private final OnPageChangeCallback callback;


public interface OnPageChangeCallback {
    void onPageSelected(int position);
}

public TabAdapter(BaseFragment fragment, TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager2 viewPager, TabFragment... fragments) {
    this(fragment, tabLayout, viewPager, Arrays.asList(fragments), null);
}

public TabAdapter(BaseFragment fragment, TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager2 viewPager, List<TabFragment> fragments) {
    this(fragment, tabLayout, viewPager, fragments, null);
}

public TabAdapter(BaseFragment fragment, TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager2 viewPager, List<TabFragment> fragments, OnPageChangeCallback listener) {
    super(fragment);
    this.mFragments = fragments;
    this.prefix = fragment.TAG;
    this.mViewPager = viewPager;
    this.mTabLayout = tabLayout;
    this.callback = listener;
    initTabLayout();

}

@Override
@NonNull
public BaseFragment<?> createFragment(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position).getFragment();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Objects.hash(mFragments.get(position));
}

@Override
public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
    for (TabFragment fragment : mFragments) {
        if (Objects.hash(fragment) == itemId) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

private void initTabLayout() {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
       
            if (callback != null) callback.onPageSelected(position);
            TabStateProvider.saveTab(prefix, position);
        }
    });
    int startTab = TabStateProvider.getTab(prefix, false, 0);

    new TabLayoutMediator(mTabLayout, mViewPager, (tab, position) -> {
        tab.setText(mFragments.get(position).getTabTitle());
    }).attach();

    selectPage(startTab);

}

void selectPage(int pageIndex) {
    mViewPager.post(() -> {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex, false);
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the ConstraintLayout in your fragment layout and check again.

Comment: This indeed works...but if I remove this. My EditText (that is on the same fragment) will stay hidden behind the keyboard when I try to enter text. So I need the fitsSystemWindows flag for the keyboard to work properly, but with it i have the weired margin. Ideas how to remove it?

Comment: what is ***android:layout_weight*** for?

Comment: @Avinta Try to remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from your fragment and add it into the root-LinearLayout of your Activity so to consume the window insets there. If that doesn't work try to completely remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and  declare the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into your Activity manifest file to solve the keyboard issue.